# Why can't a peerDependency be imported or required, even when it's present in the parent module?

Tags: javascript, npm, peer-dependencies

I'm trying to use npm `peerDependencies` but nothing seems to work as advertised. What am I missing?

The setup is, I have two modules, `mod` and `plugin`, both of which depend on an external module from npm. `mod` declares a hard dependency on both `plugin` and the external module, and the plugin declares a peer dependency, in order to get access to the version being used by the parent module.

The files look like this:

```
~/plugin/package.json:

    {
      "name": "plugin",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "main": "index.js",
      "peerDependencies": {
        "pad-right": "^0.2.2"
      }
    }

~/plugin/index.js

    var peerDependency = require('pad-right')
    module.exports = 'this is a plugin'

~/mod/package.json:

    {
      "name": "mod",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "main": "index.js",
      "dependencies": {
        "pad-right": "^0.2.2",
        "plugin": "../plugin"
      }
    }

~/mod/index.js:

    var hardDependency = require('pad-right')
    var plugin = require('plugin')
```

As I understand it from docs and examples, I think this should be a standard way to use peer dependencies, and running `npm install` in either directory doesn't give any errors or warnings.

However when I run webpack in the `mod` folder, I get errors like:

```sh
ERROR in ../plugin/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'pad-right' in '~/plugin'
 @ ../plugin/index.js 1:21-41
 @ ./index.js
```

What's going wrong here, shouldn't webpack resolve the require statement inside `plugin` with the peer dependency from the parent `mod` module?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gah, it looks like this is an edge case that only affects modules that are referencing each other locally via the file system.

The solution is apparently to add something like:

```
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'pad-right': path.resolve('node_modules', 'pad-right'),
        },
    },
```

to your webpack config. (Or else to try `resolve.symlinks: false`, which solves the problem in the minimal repro code I posted, but doesn't solve things in my actual project).

[Article about the issue](https://medium.com/@penx/managing-dependencies-in-a-node-package-so-that-they-are-compatible-with-npm-link-61befa5aaca7)

Comment: What file is this in?